# Visualising data counts by day overlaid with key events

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm working with twitter data related to two different keywords.I want to count the number of tweets per day for each keyword, visualise the results on a line graph, then overlay that with the dates of a range of significant calendar events.

My aim is to see whether tweet counts change around specific events. I've already counted and visualised the tweets, but am having problems figuring out how to overlay key dates.

I tried putting the important dates into a list, but it threw an error. Could anyone give me some pointers or suggest a better way to approach this?

Here's an image that gives a rough idea of what I'm trying to achieve:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpsCg.jpg

```
dates_list = ['2016-06-16','2016-06-23', '2016-06-24',
             '2016-07-02', '2016-07-13']

#then convert list into a Series

key_dates = pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(dates_list))

# add columns to identify important events, and mark a 0 or 1.
tweet_trend['Important Events'] = False
tweet_trend.loc[key_dates, 'Important Events'] = True
tweet_trend['values'] = 0
tweet_trend.loc[key_dates, 'values'] = 1
```

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-88-04dd081adc28> in <module>
     10 # add columns to identify important events, and mark a 0 or 1.
     11 tweet_trend['Important Events'] = False
---> 12 tweet_trend.loc[key_dates, 'Important Events'] = True
     13 tweet_trend['values'] = 0
     14 tweet_trend.loc[key_dates, 'values'] = 1

~/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
    187         else:
    188             key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
--> 189         indexer = self._get_setitem_indexer(key)
    190         self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
    191 

~/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _get_setitem_indexer(self, key)
    165         if isinstance(key, tuple):
    166             try:
--> 167                 return self._convert_tuple(key, is_setter=True)
    168             except IndexingError:
    169                 pass

~/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _convert_tuple(self, key, is_setter)
    246                 if i >= self.obj.ndim:
    247                     raise IndexingError('Too many indexers')
--> 248                 idx = self._convert_to_indexer(k, axis=i, is_setter=is_setter)
    249                 keyidx.append(idx)
    250         return tuple(keyidx)

~/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _convert_to_indexer(self, obj, axis, is_setter, raise_missing)
   1352                 kwargs = {'raise_missing': True if is_setter else
   1353                           raise_missing}
-> 1354                 return self._get_listlike_indexer(obj, axis, **kwargs)[1]
   1355         else:
   1356             try:

~/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _get_listlike_indexer(self, key, axis, raise_missing)
   1159         self._validate_read_indexer(keyarr, indexer,
   1160                                     o._get_axis_number(axis),
-> 1161                                     raise_missing=raise_missing)
   1162         return keyarr, indexer
   1163 

~/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _validate_read_indexer(self, key, indexer, axis, raise_missing)
   1250             if not(self.name == 'loc' and not raise_missing):
   1251                 not_found = list(set(key) - set(ax))
-> 1252                 raise KeyError("{} not in index".format(not_found))
   1253 
   1254             # we skip the warning on Categorical/Interval

KeyError: "[Timestamp('2016-06-16 00:00:00')] not in index"
```

Comment: it's not clear, what exactly you are trying to achieve here? Do you want to filter the rows with the KEY_DATES ?

Comment: I'm trying to somehow map the key_dates to the tweet counts. But I may well be trying the wrong thing. Would filtering the rows with key_dates help here? I've added an image to the original post that gives a rough idea of what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) for test membership and then casting column to integer for `True/False` to `1/0` mapping, also converting to `Series` is not necessary:

```
dates_list = ['2016-06-16','2016-06-23', '2016-06-24',
             '2016-07-02', '2016-07-13']

key_dates = pd.to_datetime(dates_list)
tweet_trend['Important Events'] = df.index.isin(key_dates)
tweet_trend['values'] = tweet_trend['Important Events'].astype(int)
```